# Javascript Countdown timer shuffles between two timers

Tags: javascript, timer, xmlhttprequest

I have the following Javascript codes

```
// COUNTDOWN TIMER
function refillTimer(refillTimer){
  var countDownDate = new Date(refillTimer).getTime();
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var hours = ("0" + Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))).slice(-2);
    var minutes = ("0" + Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))).slice(-2);
    var seconds = ("0" + Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)).slice(-2);
    document.getElementById("refillTimer").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if(distance < 0){
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("refillTimer").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    }
  }, 1000);
}

// ON SWIPE PERFORM ACTION
async function swipeAction(currentElementObj, swipeType) {
  var cardId = currentElementObj.getAttribute("value");
  var dataString = {
    card: cardId,
    swipe: swipeType
  };
  let response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "processes/swipe.php", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xhr.responseType = "json";
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataString));
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        let resObj = xhr.response;
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 && resObj) {
          if(resObj.action == 'gameover'){
            refillTimer(resObj.nextgameoverTimer);
          }else if(resObj.action == 'killsalloted'){
            refillTimer(resObj.nextkillsallotedTimer);
          }
        }
      };
    }catch(e){
      reject(e.toString());
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see in the `swipeAction()` function I have two `if` and `else if` conditions on success where I call the timers. The problem here is that once the timer is called under one condition then on being called on the other condition the timer overlaps each other. This should not happen. The timers should load individually. Which technically means that the timer function should be refreshed every time it is called or something similar. Please look at the GIF below for exact problem.

[image]

Here, one condition calls a 12 hour timer while the other calls a 24 hour timer. Both the timer are overlapping each other as shown above instead of showing the respective one only. What can be the required solution?

Comment: You install a new interval timer every time you swipe, so you have multiple different timers triggering within each second. Make sure you save the timer id (`x`) by returning it from your `refillTimer` or by storing it in a outer-scope or global variable, and `clearInterval` before you set the next one, not just when `distance` falls below zero.

Comment: Try to make the `refillTimer` more vanilla, pass the interval ID and the date object from outside, because you are creating a new inteeval ID and date object each time you call the function.

Comment: @Amadan and Kingbeencent a code answer would be much understandable and appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Put `return x` into `refillTimer`. Put `let timer` at the top of `swipeAction`, change both `refillTimer(...)` into `timer = refillTimer(...)`. Put `clearInterval(timer)` above `if(resObj.action...)`.

Alternately, change `var x = setInterval(...)` to `timer = setInterval(...)` (no `var`; also, avoid `x` as variable name, especially if it has a larger scope). Put `let timer` in front of `function refillTimer(...) { ... }`. Put `clearInterval(timer)` at the start of `refillTimer` function.

Either of these courses of action will ensure that you clear the previous interval timer before installing a new one, and thus have only one running at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. However, instead of that kind of theory explanation you could straight away edit my code for an answer. That would have been much easier to understand.

Comment: Okay I tried a different approach that works well. Can say it's a work around but working good.